# Appending Key/Value to object inside of Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

So I am currently attempting to modify a global object within a promise using the code below, however, when i console.log the object at the end, it returns 'undefined' for the key of 'id'. I'm a little confused as to why inside the success block of a promise it isn't setting the new key and value within the patient object. Thanks in advance!

```
    patient = { first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, gender: gender, dob: dob }

        postgres.findPatient(patient)
          .then(function(success){

           patient.id = success.id

          })
          .catch(function(err){
            if (err.received === 0) {
              postgres.createPatient(patient)
                .then(function(success){
                    postgres.findPatient(patient)
                    .then(function(success){
                      patient.id = success.id
                    })
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                  if (err) console.log(err);
                })
            }
          })

console.log(patient) // yields

patient = { 
      first_name: 'billy, 
      last_name: 'bob', 
      gender: 'm', 
      dob: '1970-01-01' }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Try to console.log the object *at the end*, not right after you started the asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous. You will only see the `id` key on the `patient` after the `.then()` has finished executing. Top level code is executed synchronously, so you're looking for the `id` before the promise has finished. You can only access the `id` inside a chained callback like `.then()` when the promise has guaranteed to finish.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm a little confused as to why inside the success block of a promise it isn't setting the new key and value within the patient object.

It is, however, it is not executed immediately. That is how promises work.

When your code is run, it first begins the process of finding the patient. It then runs your `console.log`. When the database query has finished, it runs your `.then` function, which sets the id. *The `console.log` is run before the `patient.id` is set.*

If you put `console.log(patient)` in the `then`, right after `patient.id = success.id`, you should see the correct result.

You will get the same result if you put it in a `then` function after the `catch` (Read more about [Promise Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)). This would probably be the best place to write code that depends on the `id`. Like this:

```
    patient = { first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, gender: gender, dob: dob }

    postgres.findPatient(patient)
      .then(function(success){

       patient.id = success.id

      })
      .catch(function(err){
        if (err.received === 0) {
          postgres.createPatient(patient)
            .then(function(success){
                postgres.findPatient(patient)
                .then(function(success){
                  patient.id = success.id
                })
            })
            .catch(function(err){
              if (err) console.log(err);
            })
        }
      })
      .then(function () {
         console.log(patient);

         // Do something with the id
      })
```

Comment: Good answer. I believe this is called [Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)

Comment: @styfle Yeah, edited the answer to add that link. Thanks!